# How to structure a list as table and send out to email?

Tags: php

How can i edit this code, so that each data will be in a table format, under a specified column for example `Sname` will be under shop name,  `pname` will be under product name.thanks

```
 $list = '';
$pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac");   
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)){ 
    $list .= $row['Sname']     .$row['Pname']     .$row['Psize']     .$row['Pcolour']     .$row['Pquantity']     .$row['Price']."\n"; 
}

//Send email
$to = $email; 
$subject = "YOUR ORDER LIST FROM REACHEASY"; 
$headers = "From: donotreply@rapsody.co.uk"; 
$body = "$list"; 
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a simple example for you.

```
 $body = "<html><body><table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Shop Name</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Color Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>";
    $pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac");   
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)){ 
        $body .= "<tr>
            <td>" . $row['Sname'] ."</td>
            <td>" . $row['Pname'] ."</td>
            <td>" . $row['Psize'] ."</td>
            <td>" . $row['Pcolour'] ."</td>
            <td>" . $row['Pquantity'] ."</td>
            </tr>";
    }

    $body .="</table></body></html>";


    //Send email
    $to = $email; 
   $subject = "YOUR ORDER LIST FROM REACHEASY"; 
$headers = "From: donotreply@rapsody.co.uk\r\n";  
$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

Comment: will i need to echo anything there, when i used the structure it basically sent the code as the email say <html><body><table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Shop Name</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th>Size</th>
<th>Color Name</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
</tr><tr>
       <td>matalan</td>
       <td>shirt</td>
       <td>23</td>
       <td>blue</td>
       <td>7</td>
       </tr></table></body></html>

Comment: No you don't need to echo this.

Comment: ok, because i tried the code, and the email i got was the code back like

Comment: <html><body><table border='1'> <tr> <th>Shop Name</th> <th>Product Name</th> <th>Size</th> <th>Color Name</th> <th>Quantity</th> </tr><tr> <td>matalan</td> <td>shirt</td> <td>23</td> <td>blue</td> <td>7</td> </tr></table></body></html>

Comment: I modified my answer since. Added MIME header as well. Please check now.

Comment: Please mark as correct answer, if you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Read [Sending Nice HTML Email with PHP](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)